# check for a folder with python

Tags: python, windows, mkdir

```
if os.chdir(path+"micro")==True:
    os.chdir(path+"micro")
else: 
    os.mkdir(path+"micro")
    os.chdir(path+"micro")
```

when I use this method it gives me an error and says file exitsts why can't I access that file

Comment: As you can see on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm, `os.chdir` do not return value. So your `if os.chdir(path+"micro")==True:` is wrong. What do you really want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code is for you:

```
if os.path.exists(path+"micro"):
    os.chdir(path+"micro")
else: 
    os.mkdir(path+"micro")
    os.chdir(path+"micro")
```

Your code was incorrect because as you can see from the documentation [os.chdir](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir) does not return any value, but is used to change the current working directory to the given path. Returns None in all the cases. For this reason your code gave an error.

Instead you need the [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) method which return True if path refers to an existing path. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some platforms, this function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
   dir = os.path.join(path, "micro")
   if not os.path.isdir(dir):
       os.mkdir(dir)
   os.chdir(dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir(path+"micro")` This does not return false if the path doesn't exist. It rather gives an error. Also writing `path + "mirco"` is not a good practice either. The standard way is using `os.path.join(path, "micro")` because it handles choosing "/" or "\" according to the os it is running on.

So these are some alternatives that you might try.

**Alternative 1:**

```
dir = os.path.join(path, "micro")
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)  
os.chdir(dir)
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
dir = os.path.join(path, "micro")
try:
    os.chdir(dir)
except:
    os.mkdir(dir)
    os.chdir(dir)
```